# Metric spaces Norm

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I got this lemma and proof from a book however I cannot understand the proof.[image] [image]

How can $\alpha\beta\leq\frac{\alpha^p}{p}+\frac{\beta^q}{q}$? What do we take from the last inequality? Sorry for print screening. Thanks for reading

Comment: The inequality is Young's inequality!

Answer (score 1):

The function $x\mapsto e^x$ is convex so $$ab = \exp(\log a+ \log b)=\exp\left(\frac{1}{p}\log a^p+\frac{1}{q}\log b^q\right)$$
$$\leq\frac{1}{p}e^{\log(a^p)}+\frac{1}{q}e^{\log(b^q)}=\frac{a^p}{p}+\frac{b^q}{q}.$$

Comment: Could you please provide me an explantation to the last inequality that concludes the proof of the lemma? Anyway thanks for the first proof!

Comment: When you write log you mean $ln$ right?

Comment: @PedroGomes convexity means that $\exp(tx+sy)\leq t\exp(x)+s\exp(y)$ provided $s+t=1$, in our case $s=1/p$ and $t=1/q$. And, yes, $\log =\ln$. Is that okay?

Comment: My doubt also lies in the substitution of $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ by $\frac{\mu_i^p}{p}$${(\Sigma{\mu_j}^p})^\frac{-1}{p}$,
$\frac{v_i^p}{p}$${(\Sigma{v_j}^q})^\frac{-1}{q}$ respectively. Could you explain the last inequality?

Comment: Do not mind I already got it.